# What does apply transform do?

Tags: transforms

I noticed apply transform changes matrix_world in some way but it did not become an identity matrix so it must be something else it is doing. Is it modifying the vertices? Is it setting matrix_basis to the identity matrix? Someone please help me understand how the GUI things relate to actual numbers :-)

Comment: [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/apply.html#apply) is the entry in the Blender manual.

Comment: I have already read that, but it doesn't go into detail about parent child relationships, constraints, bones, what is vertex data what is object data what are the orange dots edit mode vs object mode vs weight painting vs bone mode or whatever it is called... Like I want to be able to find the matrix/numbers for each thing and know exactly what it means.

Comment: "visually keeping the object data in-place":can mean pretty much anything. Like it could even mean the object is transformed into a jpg (I know that is not the case but that is the level of me not understanding how the data model works).